# Problem accessing hash imported from CSV in Perl

Tags: csv, perl

I am working with the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#SYNOPSIS) library of Perl to import data from a CSV file, using the functional interface. The data is stored in an array of hashes, and the problem is that when the script tries to access those elements/keys, they are uninitialized (or undefined).

Using the library `Dumper`, it is possible to see that the array and the hashes are not empty, in fact, they are correctly filled with the data of the CSV file.

With this small piece of code, I get the following output:

```perl
my $array = csv(
    in => $csv_file,
    headers => 'auto');
foreach my $mem (@{$array}) {
    print Dumper $mem;
    foreach (keys $mem) {
        print $mem{$_};
    }
}
```

Last part of the output:

```
    $VAR1 = {
          'Column' => '16',
          'Width' => '13',
          'Type' => 'RAM',
          'Depth' => '4096'
        };
Use of uninitialized value in print at ** line 81.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ** line 81.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ** line 81.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ** line 81.
```

This happens with all the elements of the array. Is this problem related to the encoding, or I am just simply accessing the elements in a incorrect way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$mem is a reference to a hash, but you keep trying to use it directly as a hash. Change your code to:

```
foreach (keys %$mem) {
    print $mem->{$_};
}
```

There is a slight complication in that in some versions of perl, 'keys $mem' was allowed directly as an experimental feature, which later got removed. In any case, adding

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

would likely have given you some helpful clues as to what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code on my version of Perl (5.24), I get this error:

> Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden at ... line ...

This points to the line:

```
foreach (keys $mem) {
```

You should dereference the hash ref:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::CSV qw( csv );
 
my $csv_file="data.csv";
my $array = csv(
    in => $csv_file,
    headers => 'auto');

foreach my $mem (@{$array}) {
    print Dumper($mem);
    foreach (keys %{ $mem }) {
        print $mem->{$_}, "\n";
    }
}
```